# Checking if certain file\files exist

Tags: c#, forms

I want to make a windows form using C# to check if a file exist.

I've tried this one:

```
private void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var app1 = (@"C:\Users\frangon\Desktop\Spectrum-Check.EXE");

    test.Text = File.Exists(app1).ToString();

}
```

[image: This is when what I get when I run it. test is label1.]

[image: This is when I click the label1]

If possible, I don't want to click it. I just want it to show as "True" if the file exist, or "False" if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Put ur code in the constructor then it will run when the form loads right now u are putting ur code in onClick event so it only runs when u click the button

Comment: Hi Shivam, would you please direct me on how to do that?

Comment: U should have a method named `public Test-Form` (something) like this just copy paste ur code there instead in `private void test_Click`

Comment: I still need to click if to show "True" even after changing it to public...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event to trigger when the form loads:

[image]

And then in your code behind:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string app1 = @"C:\Users\frangon\Desktop\Spectrum-Check.EXE";
    test.Text = File.Exists(app1).ToString();
}
```